# Read resource file that is outside of my project folder

Tags: asp.net, readfile

I want to read a .resx file via ResourceReader But the problem is that file is present in another projectfolder that is part of my Solution i.e. abc.sln

This is my hierarchy

(directory) / ProjectName / ProjectName.Admin / Admin.csproj
(directory) / ProjectName / ProjectName.Common / Common.csproj

Lets say i have to read my file in a controller from Admin and that file is present in Language folder of ProjectName.Common

When i use

`var path = Server.MapPath(@"\ProjectName\ProjectName.Common\Languages\Resource.resx")`

from admin it returns

```
path = directoryname:\\ProjectName\\ProjectName.Admin\\ProjectName\\ProjectName.Common\\Languages\\Resource.resx
```

Any idea how to achieve this, i.e. reading file from another project .